# What is the sum of all solutions satisfying the equations: $Cos (x)-4Sin (x)=1$

Tags: trigonometry

> What is the sum of all solutions satisfying the equations: 
>   $$\cos (x)-4\sin (x)=1$$

My try

$\cos (x)=2(\sin (\frac {x}{2}))^{2}-1$

$2(\sin (\frac {x}{2}))^{2}-1-4\times 2\sin (\frac {x}{2})\cos (\frac {x}{2})=1$

$2(\sin (\frac {x}{2}))^{2}-4×2\sin (\frac {x}{2})\cos (\frac {x}{2})=2$

$(\sin (\frac {x}{2}))^{2}-4\sin (\frac {x}{2})\cos (\frac {x}{2})=1$

$-4\sin (\frac {x}{2})\cos (\frac {x}{2})=\cos(\frac {x}{2}))^{2})$

$\cos(\frac {x}{2}))^{2} +4\sin (\frac {x}{2})\cos (\frac {x}{2}=0$

$\cos(\frac {x}{2})[\cos(\frac {x}{2}) +4\sin (\frac {x}{2} ]=0$

$\cos(\frac {x}{2})=0$   or $\cos(\frac {x}{2}) +4\sin (\frac {x}{2} )=0$

$\cos(\frac {x}{2})=0 \to \frac {x}{2}= \frac {\pi \times n}{2} \to x= \pi \times n $
where $n$ belongs to $Z$

Am i doing well?  What should I do now?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions. The sum is undefined.

Comment: @Yves Daoust  Can you elaborate you answer please?

Comment: Do you disagree about the number of solutions ?

Comment: The first line of your attempt is not right. $\cos (x)=-(2(\sin (\frac {x}{2}))^{2}-1)$

Comment: Type \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, and \cot x, respectively, when you are in math mode to produce $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, and $\cot x$.

Comment: Since I think all of us have better things to do with our time than scroll through posts and make extensive formatting edits, I’m down-voting this question until to the necessary edits are made (as outlined in the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)), at which time I will gladly recast my vote if you mention me in a comment.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor ...maybe now...? :-/

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Much better! You can also use `$$` on either end to make the math centered and slightly larger

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Too many lines... maybe... but I personally prefer it this way.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Oh, I didn’t recognize that it was you commenting and not the OP. Obviously you know all the ins and outs of MathJax!

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Lmao, okay. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos x-4 \sin x=1$$
Use substitution $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$

$$\sin x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2};\;\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
The equation becomes
$$\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}- \frac{8t}{1+t^2}=1$$
$$1-t^2-8t=1+t^2$$
$$2t^2+8t=0$$
$$2t(t+4)=0$$
Two solutions $t_1=0\to \tan\frac{x}{2}=0\to \frac{x}{2}=k\pi\to x=2k\pi,\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$

$t_2=-4\to \tan\frac{x}{2}=-4\to \frac{x}{2}=-\arctan 4+k\pi\to x=-2\arctan 4+2k\pi,\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: thank you sir for this elegant  solution,  i have a question:  $t_2=-4\to \tan\frac{x}{2}=-4\to \frac{x}{2}=-\arctan 4+k\pi\to x=-2\arctan 4+2k\pi,\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$   , isn't $\tan(x/2)$ is negative  so its should be $arctan (-4)  +k\pi$

Comment: @user373141 $\arctan (-4)=-\arctan 4$

Answer (score 0):

to solve such equations in the form
$$a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)=1$$ we can write
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(x)+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
and we get
$$\cos(\phi)\cos(x)+\sin(\phi)\sin(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
and we have $$\cos(\phi-x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$